# Respond inside callback does nothing in node Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using node Express for my backend application.
I wrote a method that gets some input from express request object. The method does some checks and write messages to the respond object via res.write(...). At the end of all checks I call res.end(); So far so good.
Some of my checks require a mongodb access therefore I have to work with callbacks. Here's some code:

```
app.post("/addUser", function (req, res) {
expdb.unique({ "email": req.body.email }, function (isUnique) {
    if (!isUnique) {
        res.write("email error");
    }
})
expdb.unique({ "_id": req.body.user }, function (isUnique) {
    if (!isUnique) {
        res.write("user error");
    }
})
/* -- below here everything works fine -- */
if (req.body.user.length < 3 || req.body.user.length > 20) {
    res.write("username to short ...or to long");
}
/* -- ... more working code -- */
res.end();
});
```

The first two responds are completely ignored.
I´m pretty sure some funky callback magic is happening here but I can't figure out how to do it right.
I tried something like below to be sure the callback knows the respond object but it also failed:

```
expdb.unique({"_id": req.body.user}, function(result, respond) {
    if(!result) {
        respond.write("user error")
    }
}, res)
```

May somebody help me with this.

thanks
-Dirk

Comment: Where are you getting the `respond` variable from in your first example? If you read the Express documentation you'd see it's `res.send` which calls `res.write` and `res.end`.

Comment: the respond was a typo. I corrected it in the question - sorry.
If I use send() instead of write() i get the "can't set headers after they are sent" error.

Comment: It's a callback; the method has run and `res.end` has been called before your callbacks run. Aren't these async functions?

Comment: @DaveNewton that's a good point. I thought about that too and tried to nest the callbacks into each other like expdb.unique(..., function(){...expd.unique(...,function(...))}). But it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kalman I finally got it right. Here's the working code for someone who's looking for it:

```
app.post("/addUser", function (req, res) {
    expdb.unique({ "email": req.body.email }, function (uniqueEmail) {
        if (!uniqueEmail) {
            res.write("Email in use\n");
        }
        expdb.unique({ "_id": req.body.user }, function (uniqueUser) {
            if (!uniqueUser) {
                res.write("Username in use\n");
            }
            if (req.body.user.length < 3 || req.body.user.length > 20) {
                res.write("username to short ...or to long\n");
            }
            /* -- other validations --*/
            res.end();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned in the comments, the following should work

```
var theEnd = function(response){
   if (req.body.user.length < 3 || req.body.user.length > 20) {
     res.write("username to short ...or to long");
   }
   /* -- ... more working code -- */
   res.end();
};

app.post("/addUser", function (req, res) {
  expdb.unique({ "email": req.body.email }, function (isUnique) {
    if (!isUnique) {
        res.write("email error");
    }
    theEnd(res);
  })
  expdb.unique({ "_id": req.body.user }, function (isUnique) {
    if (!isUnique) {
        res.write("user error");
    }
    theEnd(res);
  })
```

Comment: YAY @Kalman. That was tickling my thinkmuscles as I mentioned I've tried to nest the callbacks. But somewhere I shifted a codeblock to the wrong position and messed it up. Your answer opened my eyes. Thank you very much.